# Can't access child tag in xml using python-docx

Tags: python, xml, ms-word, python-docx

I am trying to access the name of a picture in a word document using python-docx but i also need to know which paragraph and run it is contained in so I can not use inline_shapes.

```
docx = Document()
section = docx.sections[0]
p = docx.add_paragraph()
run = p.add_run()
img = run.add_picture("pptExporter.png", 100000)
a = run._r.xml
print(a)
b = run._r.drawing.inline.graphic.graphicData.pic.nvPicPr.get('name')
p2 = docx.add_paragraph("hello", style="Caption")
docx.save("test.docx")
```

When I print the xml I get:

```
<w:r xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mo="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mac/office/2008/main" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mv="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mac:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
  <w:drawing>
    <wp:inline xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
      <wp:extent cx="100000" cy="75021"/>
      <wp:docPr id="1" name="Picture 1"/>
      <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
        <a:graphicFrameLocks noChangeAspect="1"/>
      </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
      <a:graphic>
        <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
          <pic:pic>
            <pic:nvPicPr>
              <pic:cNvPr id="0" name="pptExporter.png"/>
              <pic:cNvPicPr/>
            </pic:nvPicPr>
            <pic:blipFill>
              <a:blip r:embed="rId9"/>
              <a:stretch>
                <a:fillRect/>
              </a:stretch>
            </pic:blipFill>
            <pic:spPr>
              <a:xfrm>
                <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                <a:ext cx="100000" cy="75021"/>
              </a:xfrm>
              <a:prstGeom prst="rect"/>
            </pic:spPr>
          </pic:pic>
        </a:graphicData>
      </a:graphic>
    </wp:inline>
  </w:drawing>
</w:r>
```

but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file", line 11, in <module>
    b = run._r.drawing.inline.graphic.graphicData.pic.nvPicPr.get('name')
AttributeError: 'CT_R' object has no attribute 'drawing'
```

Comment: The first snippet of code is only test code is an attempt to get the name pptExport.png from the xml code

Comment: Has this part of python-docx changed since this conversation https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/249 ?

Comment: No its pretty much the same, i can get the name from img._inline.graphic .....get("name")  however i need to know which paragraph and run the image is located in